# onGlobalLayout() called without apparent layout change

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-autocomplete, android-viewtreeobserver

I have a soft keyboard listener that works well (except for one activity).  Here it is.

```
public static void setKeyboardListener(final Activity activity, final ImageView iv_header){
    final View view =activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout(){

            //get cached screen height
            String s_heightRoot =StringCacheFactory.stringCache.get("screen_height");
            int heightRoot = (s_heightRoot ==null) ? 0 : FormatFactory.tryParseStringToInt(s_heightRoot);

            //get height when onGlobalLayout is called
            Rect measureNewRect = new Rect();
            view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(measureNewRect);
            int heightNew =measureNewRect.bottom;

            if ((heightNew < heightRoot) || (heightRoot ==0)){
                //screen has shrunk, keyboard open, perform awesome code
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }else{
                //full screen, do nothing
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For all activities, the listener waits for a screen change then calls onGlobalLayout().  But one activity, onGlobalLayout() gets called immediately (without a screen change).  This activity is fairly unique in that it impliments the following

```
public class PlacesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    //lotsa code
}
```

`PlacesActivity` has an `AutoCompleteTextView` where the user selects a worldwide city with help from Google Places API.  Do these callbacks mess with my `onGlobalLayoutListener`?

Any other situations where `onGLobalLayout()` can be called without an apparent layout change?

Does the `AutoCompleteTextView` trigger the `onGlobalLayout()`?

Comment: `onGlobalLayout()` is for the entire View tree. If something in your layout changes (an EditText gains focus) it'll be called.

Comment: So, I changed my code to create a second listener immediately after the first one is closed (hoping to test the gaining focus idea).  Both get called as soon as the activity starts.  Also to add, I was in error when I wrote "edit text", it is actually an "AutoCompleteTextView".  Not sure if that has something to do with it.